Martial Arts movie where fight takes place in gym
There was a Martial Arts movie I remember seeing as a kid that featured 2 male fighters; one was a serious fighter and the other was comic relief.  The one specific scene I can remember is the final fight at the end, where the 2 guys fight another guy in a gym.  The guy they fight uses weights to fight them, but, of course, he loses.  I thought it was a Bruce Lee movie, but it doesn't really seem Bruce Lee did that many fighting movies.  I could be wrong, though.
Sorry, I saw this movie in the early 80's, so it wasn't Dragon.  It was just 2 guys versus the one guy at the end...  I was in Atlanta at the time and I think it was on Kung Fu Theater, or was it Kung Fu Gold?  Channel 46 or 69... =-)

Can you elaborate when is your childhood? 80's? 90's?

There is a fight scene in sort of a gym in "Dragon: The Bruce Lee Story", but if i remember correctly it doesn't match your description.

It would have been channel 69 and they showed 70's martial arts films as well. Can you narrow it down by saying whether it was a period (ancient china) film or modern?

I am pretty sure it was more modern.  What is another site where I could submit this question.  As I thought about it, I am not 100% sure 69 was around in the 80s.  I may have been 2 or 5 during the afternoon.  In my Babs voice "Memories blah blah blah"

Sounds like it might be a Bruce Lee parody/spoof/comedy reference btw.

Wasn't a spoof the fighting was good.  @poepje I fixed it guess I need to proofread...

@arinte oh silly me, haha. I should've gotten that it was a simple typo, but I didn't realise Dragon is the name of a movie. :)

In Dragon there is a scene in a gym where a big guy demands that Bruce puts the weights down because it is their turn.  He refuses and they attempt to intimidate him but he challenges him to a fight and makes some comic one liners.
The rest of this guys friends join in when their champion is losing and Bruce fights all of them.
Could this be it?
